# How do I add a multi-line listview from 3 separate xml string-arrays in android?

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

I'm trying to make a listview that will have 3 lines of text one below the other (so 3 lines of text stacked on top of each other) that has the text content coming from 3 separate xml string-array files. The code I have so far is attached below. I have not added the 3rd xml string-array yet so no need to address that in your answer to me.

I've been looking all over for a few days to find out how to do this but simply cant find the answer. I've found how to add multi-line listviews inline with java code but I need the list items to be bound to 3 separate xml string arrays in order to make it easier to update them remotely as well as for speed purposes.

Any help out would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  String [] movie_name = getResources() .getStringArray(R.array.movie_name_array);
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.movie_name, movie_name));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  String [] movie_date = getResources() .getStringArray(R.array.movie_date_array);
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.movie_date, movie_date));

  ListView lv1 = getListView();
  lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your own layout adapter class in order to provide the listview with a proper view to display your data (ie, you array of 3 strings).

Check this example here : 
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

It's quite important to understand how to build the kind of components in android. Enjoy.

Stéphane

Comment: I should have been more specific. I want to have a multi line listview using xml string arrays, not a java based string array. I have edited my original post to reflect that as well.

Comment: What's the difference ? The same will apply, the only difference is the way you acquire your data.